# Realm objects overriden equals method

Tags: android, realm

My model for `ObjectA` looks like this:

```
public class ObjectA extends RealmObject {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object objectA) {

    }
}
```

In one of my fragments I have an edit form to change attributes of an instance of `ObjectA`, and I want to present a discard changes dialogs when user backpressed out of this fragment.

In this fragment I have a reference to a simple POJO of the `objectA` I'm editing. It looks like this:

```
    public ObjectA objectA;
    public ObjectA originalObjectA = realm.copyFromRealm(objectA);
```

Now that we can override `equals` method in our realm models I can detect changes, but in order to get a call to my overriden method I have to do it like this:

```
    originalObjectA.equals(objectA);
```

not the other way around:

```
    objectA.equals(originalObjectA);
```

Any idea why I can only call my custom equals method from a POJO reference and not my live realm object?

Comment: Which version of Realm are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 0.88.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We fixed a bug in 0.88.3 that caused custom equal methods to be overwritten. It sounds like you are getting hit by that bug: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Upgrading to 0.88.3 or 0.90.0 should solve the problem.